# Preventing unique fields to be entered into database

Tags: php, oop

Here I am trying to make "Email" & "Mobile" as unique fields. But if 1 field is working other is not working, means if email is unique and mobile is not, the form is getting submitted. If both are unique the alert is properly working. My problem is "the form should not get submitted if alteast one field is not unique". this is the code...

```
    submitHandler: function(form) {



       var email = form.Email.value;
        var AgencyID = form.AgencyID.value;

        $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost/trans/admin/checkemail.php?email="+email,
        type:"post",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            if(data.length>0 && !AgencyID){
                alert("Email Already Exists");
            }else{
                form.submit();
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
             alert('request failed'+errorThrown);
        }

        });

        //mobile..................................................

        var mobile = form.Mobile.value;
        var AgencyID = form.AgencyID.value;

        $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost/trans/admin/checkmobile.php?mobile="+mobile,
        type:"post",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            if(data.length>0 && !AgencyID){
                alert("Mobile number Already Exists");
            }else{
                form.submit();
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
             alert('request failed'+errorThrown);
        }

        });



    }



});
```

Comment: because you're doing two separate ajax, and both are submitting the form on success. combine both check pages into one and do it all at the same time. Or, create a variable for emailSuccess and set it on your first ajax accordingly, and remove the form.submit() then in your mobile ajax success check the email var, post your error alerts or submit form then

Comment: can u please correct the code, I have little knowledge on ajax

Comment: no, sorry, that's your job.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion it is better to change code to use one request to the server and send there both values email and mobile.
But just to fix your code (sorry, I did't debug that, but you must get an idea):

```
    submitHandler: function(form) {
       var email = form.Email.value;
        var AgencyID = form.AgencyID.value;
var checkOK = 'TRUE';
        $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost/trans/admin/checkemail.php?email="+email,
        type:"post",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            if(data.length>0 && !AgencyID){
                alert("Email Already Exists");
                checkOK = 'FALSE';
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
             alert('request failed'+errorThrown);
        }

        });

        //mobile..................................................

        var mobile = form.Mobile.value;
        var AgencyID = form.AgencyID.value;

        $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost/trans/admin/checkmobile.php?mobile="+mobile,
        type:"post",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            if(data.length>0 && !AgencyID){
                alert("Mobile number Already Exists");
                checkOK = 'FALSE';
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
             alert('request failed'+errorThrown);
        }
        });
        if (checkOK == 'TRUE') {
            form.submit();
        }
    }
});
```